# Function executing order in an if statement php

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to make a function for a "secure" php page that will check the token(the one passed by post and the one from the session).
      But I don't want to write two if statements like this:

```
function CheckToken(){
    if(isset($_POST['token']) && isset($_SESSION['token']))
        if($_POST['token']==$_SESSION['token']) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Can I do something like this(?):

```
function CheckToken(){
    if(isset($_POST['token']) && isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_POST['token']==$_SESSION['token']) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Here's all about the order in which those functions are executed (when using the and operator).So if you're using the AND operand then if the first conditions is false don't evaluate the second.  I remember that vb.net had a solution to this problem(evaluating only the first function-if it is false don't evaluate the second one).
     So, is it safe to put everything on a single line(like I did in the second example)?

Comment: i would always stick with the first option as i like to seperate out my conditions. This is usaully to diagnose problems and also to return seperate error messages depending on the state. But if you're not worried about returning errors to users etc. Then either one is fine. Both essientially do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP does the same thing as the usual `if` statement evaluation in other major languages, that is, check from left to right.

So if you have

```
if (cond1 && cond2 && cond3)
```

**Scenario 1:**
If `cond1` is true, it will then execute `cond2`, and then `cond3`.
Sample: https://3v4l.org/Ap9SQ

**Scenario 2:**
If let's say `cond2` is `false`, then `cond3` will be ignored.
Sample: https://3v4l.org/u9P4O

Same goes to OR

```
if (cond1 || cond2 || cond3)
```

If `cond1` is true, `cond2` and `cond3` will be skipped.
Sample: https://3v4l.org/ZAZcD

---

So since your function is just returning `true` or `false`, you can even simplify it to something like this:

```
function CheckToken() {
    return isset($_POST['token']) &&
           isset($_SESSION['token']) &&
           $_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token'];
}
```

*Split lines for readability*. Also checkout [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) manual as you can pass in multiple variables for empty checking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there really is no difference to changing the order like that. It is perfectly safe, because all it's doing is changing the look of the script while the execution is the EXACT same.

It would be best to do the second option.